# Voice Command Service in wp8.1 (not silverlight)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I'm trying to use voice command service in windows phone 8.1 application, but I can't find the appropriate namespace (Windows.Phone.Speech).

Is it only available in wp8 or Silverlight ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this question while looking for the answer to this myself today; so hopefully this will help someone else.

Yes!  It does exist in Windows Phone 8.1 (WinRT).  It is now called VoiceCommandManager however, and is under Windows.Media.SpeechRecognition:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.media.speechrecognition.voicecommandmanager.aspx

Noting also that they are deprecating this in Windows 10 (there is a note to that effect on the page), which probably accounts for why this was so hard to track down.  I also found this handy sample project:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Voice-Commands-for-Windows-2f808ac6/